# yamldecode in terraform for multiple list

Tags: terraform, yaml

I am using the following yaml to get tag information for my outputs.tf.

yaml file:

```
---
common_tags:
   TAG:type: lab
   TAG:bu: crm
  
account_list: 
    friendly_name: 
        TAG:name: salesforce
        TAG:aws_regions: eu-central-1
    workload_accounts:
        TAG:account_name: some-sf-acc
        TAG:acc-no: 1234567890
        TAG:environment: development
    resource_tags:
      - vpc_name: mgmt
        TAG:name: mgmt-vpc
        TAG:owner: AutoScaling
        TAG:role: pipeline
        TAG:product: sf1
        TAG:app-id: app-id
      - vpc_name: app
        TAG:name: conftest
        TAG:owner: devops-cloud@test.com
        TAG:role: development
        TAG:product: sf2
        TAG:app-id: vcob
      - vpc_name: app
        TAG:name: app-vpc
        TAG:owner: devops-cloud@test.com
        TAG:role: automation
        TAG:product: sf3
        TAG:app-id: ser2
      - vpc_name: app
        TAG:name: conftest
        TAG:owner: devops-cloud@test.com
        TAG:role: build
        TAG:product: sf4
        TAG:app-id: entdb
```

My outputs.tf is as below:

```
output "product" {
    value = [yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["account_list"]["resource_tags"][0]["TAG:product"]
}

output "bu" {
    value = yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["common_tags"]["TAG:bu"]
}

output "acc-no" {
    value = yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["account_list"]["workload_accounts"]["TAG:acc-no"]
}

output "role" {
    value = yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["account_list"]["resource_tags"][0]["TAG:role"]
}

output "environment" {
    value = yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["account_list"]["workload_accounts"]["TAG:environment"]
}

output "type" {
    value = yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["common_tags"]["TAG:type"]
}
```

The plan gives this output:

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:

- acc-no      = 1234567890
- bu          = "crm"
- environment = "development"
- product     = "sf1"
- role        = "pipeline"
- type        = "lab"

I want to display all the products and roles in my output as below.

Expected output:

Changes to Outputs:

- acc-no      = 1234567890
- bu          = "crm"
- environment = "development"
- product     = "sf1","sf2","sf3"
- role        = "pipeline","development","automation","build"
- type        = "lab"

Please tell me how can I do it using yamldecode.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the current output, and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [splat](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) (i.e. `*`):

```
output "product" {
    value = yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["account_list"]["resource_tags"][*]["TAG:product"]
}

output "role" {
    value = yamldecode(file("resource/rnd/amc.yaml"))["account_list"]["resource_tags"][*]["TAG:role"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With my multidecoder for YAML and JSON you are able to access multiple YAML and/or JSON files with their relative paths in one step.

Documentations can be found here:

### Terraform Registry -

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/levmel/yaml_json/multidecoder/latest?tab=inputs

### GitHub:

https://github.com/levmel/terraform-multidecoder-yaml_json

### Usage

Place this module in the location where you need to access multiple different YAML and/or JSON files (different paths possible) and pass
your path/-s in the parameter **filepaths** which takes a set of strings of the relative paths of YAML and/or JSON files as an argument. You can change the module name if you want!

```
module "yaml_json_decoder" {
  source  = "levmel/yaml_json/multidecoder"
  version = "0.2.1"
  filepaths = ["routes/nsg_rules.yml", "failover/cosmosdb.json", "network/private_endpoints/*.yaml", "network/private_links/config_file.yml", "network/private_endpoints/*.yml", "pipeline/config/*.json"]
}
```

#### Patterns to access YAML and/or JSON files from relative paths:

To be able to access all YAML and/or JSON files in a folder entern your path as follows `"folder/rest_of_folders/*.yaml"`, `"folder/rest_of_folders/*.yml"` or `"folder/rest_of_folders/*.json"`.

To be able to access a specific YAML and/or a JSON file in a folder structure use this `"folder/rest_of_folders/name_of_yaml.yaml"`, `"folder/rest_of_folders/name_of_yaml.yml"` or `"folder/rest_of_folders/name_of_yaml.json"`

If you like to select all YAML and/or JSON files within a folder, then you should use **"*.yml"**, **"*.yaml"**, **"*.json"** format notation. (see above in the USAGE section)

#### YAML delimiter support is available from version 0.1.0!

**WARNING:** Only the relative path must be specified. The path.root (it is included in the module by default) should not be passed, but everything after it.

### Access YAML and JSON entries

Now you can access all entries within all the YAML and/or JSON files you've selected like that: **"module.yaml_json_decoder.files.[name of your YAML or JSON file].entry"**. If the name of your YAML or JSON file is "name_of_your_config_file" then access it as follows **"module.yaml_json_decoder.files.name_of_your_config_file.entry"**.

### Example of multi YAML and JSON file accesses from different paths (directories)

#### first YAML file:

routes/nsg_rules.yml

```
rdp:
  name: rdp
  priority: 80
  direction: Inbound
  access: Allow
  protocol: Tcp
  source_port_range: "*"
  destination_port_range: 3399
  source_address_prefix: VirtualNetwork
  destination_address_prefix: "*"
  
---
  
ssh:
  name: ssh
  priority: 70
  direction: Inbound
  access: Allow
  protocol: Tcp
  source_port_range: "*"
  destination_port_range: 24
  source_address_prefix: VirtualNetwork
  destination_address_prefix: "*"
```

#### second YAML file:

services/logging/monitoring.yml

```
application_insights:
  application_type: other
  retention_in_days: 30
  daily_data_cap_in_gb: 20
  daily_data_cap_notifications_disabled: true
  logs:
  # Optional fields
   - "AppMetrics"
   - "AppAvailabilityResults"
   - "AppEvents"
   - "AppDependencies"
   - "AppBrowserTimings"
   - "AppExceptions"
   - "AppExceptions"
   - "AppPerformanceCounters"
   - "AppRequests"
   - "AppSystemEvents"
   - "AppTraces"
```

#### first JSON file:

test/config/json_history.json

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.tf

```
module "yaml_json_multidecoder" {
  source  = "levmel/yaml_json/multidecoder"
  version = "0.2.1"
  filepaths = ["routes/nsg_rules.yml", "services/logging/monitoring.yml", test/config/*.json]
}

output "nsg_rules_entry" {
  value = module.yaml_json_multidecoder.files.nsg_rules.aks.ssh.source_address_prefix
}

output "application_insights_entry" {
  value = module.yaml_json_multidecoder.files.monitoring.application_insights.daily_data_cap_in_gb
}

output "json_history" {
  value = module.yaml_json_multidecoder.files.json_history.glossary.title
}
```

---

Changes to Outputs:

- nsg_rules_entry            = "VirtualNetwork"
- application_insights_entry = 20
- json_history               = "example glossary"